# Searching a file (grep/awk) for 2 carriage return/line-feed characters

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I'm trying to write a script that'll simply count the occurrences of \r\n\r\n in a file. (Opening the sample file in vim binary mode shows me the ^M character in the proper places, and the newline is still read as a newline).

Anyway, I know there are tons of solutions, but they don't seem to get me what I want.

e.g. `awk -e '/\r/,/\r/!d'` or using `$'\n'` as part of the grep statement.

However, none of these seem to produce what I need. I can't find the `\r\n\r\n` pattern with grep's "trick", since that just expands one variable. The awk solution is greedy, and so gets me way more lines than I want/need.

Switching grep to binary/Perl/no-newline mode seems to be closer to what I want,
e.g. `grep -UPzo '\x0D'`, but really what I want then is `grep -UPzo '\x0D\x00\x0D\x00'`, which doesn't produce the output I want.

It seems like such a simple task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, awk treats `\n` as the record separator. That makes it very hard to count `\r\n\r\n`.  If we choose some other record separator, say a letter, then we can easily count the appearance of  this combination.  Thus:

```
awk '{n+=gsub("\r\n\r\n", "")} END{print n}' RS='a' file
```

Here, `gsub` returns the number of substitutions made.  These are summed and, after the end of the `file` has been reached, we print the total number.

#### Example

Here, we use bash's `$'...'` construct to explicitly add newlines and linefeeds:

```
$ echo -n $'\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\na' | awk '{n+=gsub("\r\n\r\n", "")} END{print n}' RS='a' 
2
```

### Alternate solution (GNU awk)

We can tell it to treat `\r\n\r\n` as the record separator and then return the count (minus 1) of the number of records:

```
 cat file <(echo 1) | awk 'END{print NR-1;}' RS='\r\n\r\n'
```

In awk, `RS` is the record separator and `NR` is the count of the number of records.  Since we are using a multiple-character record separator, this requires GNU awk.

If the file ends with `\r\n\r\n`, the above would be off by one.  To avoid that, the `echo -n 1` statement is used to assure that there are always at least one character after the last `\r\n\r\n` in the file.

#### Examples

Here, we use bash's `$'...'` construct to explicitly add newlines and linefeeds:

```
$ echo -n $'abc\r\n\r\n' | cat - <(echo 1) | awk 'END{print NR-1;}' RS='\r\n\r\n'
1
$ echo -n $'abc\r\n\r\ndef' | cat - <(echo 1) | awk 'END{print NR-1;}' RS='\r\n\r\n'
1
$ echo -n $'\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n' | cat - <(echo 1) | awk 'END{print NR-1;}' RS='\r\n\r\n'
2
$ echo -n $'1\r\n\r\n2\r\n\r\n3' | cat - <(echo 1) | awk 'END{print NR-1;}' RS='\r\n\r\n'
2
```

Comment: Not all implementations of `awk` may allow an arbitrary regular expression for the value of `RS`; GNU `awk` does, but in POSIX `awk`, a multicharacter  `RS` produces undefined results.

Comment: @chepner OK.  So, the first solution, with the single character `RS`, is portable.  The second isn't.  I updated the answer to state that the second was limited to GNU awk.  Thanks for the info!